# Multidimension array displayed as dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, arrays, menu

I'd like to display my array as a menu. It's easy when the array is in one dimension - I can easily use for loop to generate one. But now my menu array looks like this:

```
$menu = array("item1", "item2", "item3" => array("subitem1", "subitem2", "subitem3"), "item4", "item5", "item6"); // hope it's defined coreectly
```

So if there is a single element in main array $menu like item1 or item5 I'd like to to display it as a plain

tags, but if one of those elements got inner elements like item3 does, I want to display it as a

```
<li>item3
<ul>
<li>subitem1</li>
<li>subitem2</li>
<li>subitem3</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I suppose I need to use for loop inside a for loop, but probably there is a simplier way.

Regards, and thanks in advance
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use nested function for that.

**CODE UPDATED**

and here is a fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tac-3jh

```
<?php
$menu = array("item1", "item2", "item3" => array("subitem1", "subitem2", "subitem3"), "item4", "item5", "item6");

function arr2ul($arr){
    $ret='';
    if (is_array($arr)){
    $ret='<ul>';
        foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
            if(is_array($val)){
                $ret.='<li>'.$key;
                $ret.=arr2ul($val);
                $ret.='</li>';
            }else{
                $ret.='<li>'.$val.'</li>';
            }
        }
        $ret.='</ul>';
    }
    return $ret;
}

$result=arr2ul($menu);// contains the html output and you
// can echo it where you want

echo $result;
?>
```

OUTPUT: (like this)

```
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2
        <ul>
            <li>sub item<li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: This won't work right. Sometimes the item name is in the key, and sometimes in the val.  Your output would be 0, 1, item3, etc.

Comment: Thanks @StevenMoseley - and +1 for your answer. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You could use recursion, which would have the added benefit of being able to traverse infinite levels of submenus:

```
function renderList($array) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($array as $key => $item)) {
        echo "<li>";
        if (is_array($item) {
            echo $key;
            renderList($item);
        } else {
            echo $item;
        }
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

$menu = array("item1", "item2", "item3" => array("subitem1", "subitem2", "subitem3"), "item4", "item5", "item6");
renderList($menu);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2p8-erq

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
$menu = array("item1", "item2", "item3" => array("subitem1", "subitem2", "subitem3"), "item4", "item5", "item6"); // hope it's defined coreectly
setfunction($menu);
function setfunction($menu){

echo "<ul>";
foreach ($menu as $key => $item) {
        echo "<li>";
        if(is_array($item))
        {
            echo $key;
            setfunction($item);
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo $item;
        }
        echo "</li>";
    }
echo "</ul>";
}

?>
```

Output

```
item1
item2
item3
    subitem1
    subitem2
    subitem3
item4
item5
item6
```